# The "Why have I been limited to one question per week?" setting

Tags: support, moderation, question-quality, user-accounts, etiquette

I've noticed that https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/question-limited is a thing.

I've also noticed that we have a user who for a while has been spamming the site with (IMHO) poor-quality (and certainly poorly-researched) questions, virtually on a daily basis when I last checked, and generally giving the firm impression that if *the very first thing* they attempted didn't work in any situation, their very next course of action was to post a question here rather than make any attempt to research or otherwise figure things out for themselves.

(I also have a feeling they've switched to a new user account today, but I'm not certain.)

My impression is that this may have been bugging me more than it's been bugging others, but just in case... the aforementioned rate-limiting restrictions might be considered.

Comment: Well let's just call it -- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/38685?tab=questions and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/38250?tab=questions are blatantly the same person.  I strongly suspect they've switched to a new user either because too many people had explicitly criticised them and they were hoping to avoid the negative associations (in which case they really haven't gotten the point); or perhaps they actually did get restricted per my linked documentation and are attempting to bypass those restrictions (which would be in direct violation of that documentation).

Comment: And maybe now https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/38707?tab=questions.

Comment: Definitely that, and perhaps now https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/38742?tab=questions.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/38810?tab=questions

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/39102?tab=questions

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/39190?tab=questions

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/39334?tab=questions

Comment: Enough is enough, no?  Can this person please be banned?  The questions continue to be of shockingly poor quality on average, and I think their willingness to waste people's time is outrageous.

Comment: I was going to ask whether this person is allowed to have so many identities and I was going to try to list them all, but you beat me to it (and have a few I had forgotten about). I'm not sure that multiple identities can be detected (I don't know how SE identifies people), but if they can, I'm certainly in favor of limiting the number of questions that this person can submit (maybe one per day?) together with a caution. Banning them would be the next step, But if all SE requires is an email address, what's to stop this person from creating new identities with burner email addresses?

Comment: BTW, he is now posting as https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/37397/veak

Comment: And also BTW, he posts the same questions on both Emacs SE and gnu.emacs.help: see e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74837/making-an-array-in-a-let-clause and https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2022-12/msg00107.html

Comment: I'm not sure about this (it's been a while), but perhaps https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/40689/pampalula (who is also https://stackoverflow.com/users/22044059/josip ) is their latest incarnation.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391095/184087 is my current approach to this issue.  Posting here in case it proves helpful to others as well.